# How can we unlock a Content when the binary saving went wrong while in a multistep save operation?

Tags: sensenet

If for any reason, an exception occurs during a multistep save operation, the Content is left in an inconsistent state.
When the binary saving went wrong, we could normally delete such wrong upload with the ForceDelete action. But here, the content is somehow also locked by this multistep save operation.
The upload cannot be resumed; it cannot be deleted, or moved to the trash.

Answer (score 1):

We found a solution for you:

You can unlock the broken files with an odata request.
Change and fill the **bold** text if needed!

1, You need to select your user ID from portal:
https://**example.com**/odata.svc//Root/IMS/**BuiltIn**/**Portal**/('**{Your username}**')?metadata=no&$select=Id

2, Then you have to run this javascript ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/OData.svc//Root/Sites/example/workspaces/Document/PSR-LU/Document_Library/2014/('sample.doc')/TakeLockOver", // change the content path
     dataType: "json",
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify({
         'user': "000000" // change to your user ID
     }),
     success: function () {
console.log("success");
     }
});
```

This code unlocks the file and changes the content owner to your user. After this moves you can delete the content itself.